# deploying a signed midlet in nokia 6131

Tags: java-me, midlet

I am trying to deploy a signed midlet in Nokia 6131 over the air using VeriSign certificate but while installing I am getting message "No valid certificate". Do I need to sign the .jar file also?

Answer (score 1):

VeriSign certificates don't need any special configuration on Nokia devices. Check your time/date settings, cause maybe the date of the device is set to default (probably 1st of Juanuary of some years ago) when the certificate was not valid yet, or more improbably, after the certificate expires.

Remember you've got to use a `VeriSign Class 3` certificate. And well, you actually have to sign the JAR, and the signature is contained in the JAD.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have a VeriSign Class 3 certificate and it is valid from 17 Feb, 2011. The signature is there in the JAD but still I am  getting "No valid certificate" message. Do I have to explicitly sign the JAR and update its information in the JAD file?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure of this, but I think, when you sign a JAR, the result is stored in the JAD, so the JAR would be the same. But, if you had an unsigned JAR, and you changed just one character of the project, then you need to replace both the JAR and the JAD. It's to say, the version of the JAD must be the same as the JAR.

Comment: Well actually I have to access memory of internal NFC card in Nokia 6131 for which the application has to be signed. I am using Sun java wireless toolkit to sign the midlet. In case I deploy the jar through PC Suit, the application is getting SecurityException and when I try to deploy the application over the air it is getting the above message while installation

Comment: Besides the certificate, you have to add the permissions. Project properties->Application Descriptor->API Permissions. I do this and deploy the midlet with PcSuite and works fine. For over-the-air install, just sign the midlet and copy and paste both files, JAR and JAD, it's all I can think of right now...

Comment: I'm sorry @user624478, with the given info I can just suggest you to try on another device or providing more info...